# Map Elements of a list to be Index of matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I have a sublist from `Tuples[{1, 2, 3}, 2]`, say for example `L={{1,2},{2,1},{2,2}}`, and a 3 x 3 matrix `M`.

My goal is to create a new list of matrices that has the same length as `L` and these matrices are the same as `M` except in the position indexed by elements of `L`,
that is replaced by some constant number `s`.

As I am used to Matlab, I did in an iterative way:

```
j=1;
While[j <= Length[L], 
  State = M;
  State[[L[[j, 1]], L[[j, 2]]]] = s;
  If[MemberQ[NewList, State] == False, AppendTo[NewList, State]];
  ++j;
];
```

but it would have be nicer to use the function `Map` I guess. So I'm looking for an elegant synthax since a little while.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are completely right: using [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) is much nicer than an iterative approach. Here's one way you might do it:

```
ReplacePart[M, # -> s]& /@ L
```

Here `/@` is a short-hand input form of `Map`, and the `#&` combination is what's known as a [pure function](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PureFunctions.html). Welcome to Mathematica :).

Comment: You don't need Map for that: `ReplacePart[M, L -> s]` works as well

Comment: @Carlo No, that gives only one matrix of which all entries indexed by `L` are replaced. The OP wants a list of matrices of which each has only one entry replaced.

Comment: There is an old syntax for `ReplacePart` that saves a couple of keystrokes:  `ReplacePart[M, s, #] & /@ L`

Comment: oh I see, sorry I misread the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `MapAt`, `Part` assignment and `MapIndexed` as follows:

```
m1 = MapAt[s &, M, #] & /@ L; 
m2 = Module[{m = M}, m[[## & @@ #]] = s; m] & /@ L;
m3 = Function[x, MapIndexed[If[#2 == x, s, #] &, M, {2}]] /@ L ;
m4 = MapIndexed[Function[{x, y}, If[y == #, s, x]], M, {2}] & /@ L ;

Equal[m1, m2, m3, m4]
```

> True

```
TeXForm[MatrixForm[m1[[1]]]]
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  a(1,1) & s & a(1,3) \\
>  a(2,1) & a(2,2) & a(2,3) \\
>  a(3,1) & a(3,2) & a(3,3) \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$,

```
TeXForm[MatrixForm[m1[[2]]]]
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  a(1,1) & a(1,2) & a(1,3) \\
>  s & a(2,2) & a(2,3) \\
>  a(3,1) & a(3,2) & a(3,3) \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$,

```
TeXForm[MatrixForm[m1[[3]]]]
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  a(1,1) & a(1,2) & a(1,3) \\
>  a(2,1) & s & a(2,3) \\
>  a(3,1) & a(3,2) & a(3,3) \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$